# jQuery ajax call getting error response with status of 200

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I sent a jQuery ajax request to my express-powered node.js server, which processed it successfully and responded.  However, the response triggers the ajax `error` callback instead of the `success` callback (despite the status code being "200").  That was not what I was expecting.  ;o)  Here is my code:

client.js:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: "/httpUpload",
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType : "json",
    data: formData,
    success: function() {
        // Do stuff
    },
    error: function( error ) {
        console.error( "HttpUpload failed: " + error.responseText );
    }
} );
```

server.js:

```
var express = require( "express" );
var app = express();
var server = require( "http" ).Server( app );
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');

app.use( express.static( "public" ) );
app.use( multipart() );

app.post( "/httpUpload", function( req, res ) {
    console.log( "Received post request");
    res.send( "Done!" );
}
```

The `error` object that I get in the ajax `error` callback looks like this:

```
{readyState: 4, responseText: "Done!", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
```

Any idea why it's triggering the `error` callback?

Comment: Hmm ... I'm not sure that I agree with your assessment.  The problem could certainly still be reproduced, and it wasn't a typographical error that was causing my problems, it was a mismatch between the requested datatype and what was returned.  In my opinion, flagging such questions discourages people from posting because they're afraid of getting a "your question is dumb" hand slap.  When I found the solution, I left my post (which I could have deleted) in case it was helpful to anyone in the future.  Such a post would have been helpful to me had it already existed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, silly me.  It's the `datatype` that I had on the ajax call.  I wasn't returning json, so it errored out.  Everything worked when I removed that.